# Soundpool game with mp3 questions

Tags: android

I am making a game which will be using questions stored on a mp3, so for each question there will be a mp3 file.

The user will then press play to hear the mp3 and then add an answer for the mp3 in an edittext field. Which would then show correct or incorrect answer.

When the user clicks confirm answer the mp3 will move to the next question. So when the user presses play it will be question 2. Is it possible to do this and if so how would I go about implementing this. I would highly appreciate any advice on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use WAV or OGG format for sounds on Android, but in any case, you can play back your MP3s with the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class. For example:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivityClass.this, R.raw.your_mp3_resource);
if(mp != null) {
    mp.start();
}
```

Read the documentation regarding state and calling release() on finished MediaPlayer objects. Alternatively use one MediaPlayer object with the setDataSource() and prepare() methods.

Comment: Thanks, so if I use that to show play one mp3 how would i get onclick to start playing another mp3? Which was my question.

Comment: Where is it recommended to use WAV or OGG? Is this due to the efficiency of playback of these files?

Comment: I'm not aware of any 'official' recommendation on files types. Uncompressed WAV files have the benefit over MP3 of not having to be uncompressed before/during playback. OGG files have the benefit over MP3 of having either 1) better compression with comparable quality, or 2) better quality with comparable compression. I'm not an audiophile, but that is my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you can use SoundPool or MediaPlayer

Both support mp3, but based on my experience, SoundPool will not always play Mp3 of more than 100kb. For those files you will have to use MediaPlayer.

[One link comparing both](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/android-soundpool-vs-mediaplayer-focus-on-soundboards-and-memory-problems/).